# WARNING:dpkg:Files list file missing for packages

Tags: dpkg

Last week, I got an error related to the following packages:

`grub-efi-amd64-signed`

`grub-pc`

`libpam-systemd:amd64`

`xserver-xorg-legacy`

The error was `Errors were encountered while processing: PACKAGE_NAME E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.

I followed a guide from it's FOSS and used these commands to temporarily fix the error:
`ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i PACKAGE_NAME` then `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE_NAME.* /tmp`.

Today, I open the terminal to install OpenRCT2 and got some new errors during the install process:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'grub-pc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-systemd:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xserver-xorg-legacy' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

While they did not affect OpenRCT2, I'm concerned they may affect my machine in the long run, and want to fix them ASAP, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged out of my account from GUI and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open tty3.

After, I logged into my account from terminal and used `sudo -i` to use the root account. I then used `apt reinstall grub-pc grub-efi-amd64-signed libpam-systemd:amd64 xserver-xorg-legacy` to reinstall the software.

This solved the problem.